# perlcc compile error on perl 5.28 while compiling to binary

Tags: perl

I compiled perl 5.28 from Source in custom path `(/usr/local/perl528)` with this options:

```
config_args='-des -Dprefix=/usr/local/perl528'
```

Then compiled B:CC in perl528 and created a `hello.pl` with the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/perl528/bin/perl

use Socket;

print "Hello world";
```

next step:

`/usr/local/perl528/perlcc -o hello hello.pl`

after execution of the ./hello, i get the following code:

```
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
panic: corrupt saved stack index -1414812757 at (eval 12) line 26.
```

Trace for ./hello:

```
27738 stat("/usr/local/perl528/lib/5.28.1/x86_64-linux/Socket.pm/auto//.so", 0x9ce0a0) = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
```

Why I get this error?

**Updates:**

- Problem only happen when using a module.
- `use strict;` is fine and causes no error but others will.
- And the code and errors are the real ones. (Yes getting error on line
  26 while i have only 6 lines of code.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `use Socket;` line necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Corion Yes, I have the problem while using a module.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and mention that the problem (only?) happens when you use a module. Also, is `Socket.pm` the only module that is problematic or does the same problem happen when adding `use strict;`? Also, do you really get an error in `line 26` as the pasted error message says? If not, please show us the real code you are running.

Comment: @Corion Updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `perlcc` tool is a fairly niche utility that is no longer part of core Perl. For a third party tool that is tightly coupled with perl internals, you are likely to see some amount of breakage when using a recent perl version.

Looking into the perlcc [Changes](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/RURBAN/B-C-1.55_10) document helps here:

- version 1.55 (the latest stable release) only added support for perl 5.24
- the development version 1.55_08 mentions perl 5.27.3, a development version of perl 5.28
- the [perl-compiler](https://github.com/rurban/perl-compiler) GitHub project mentions tests on 5.28

Therefore:

- consider installing a development version of perlcc,
- or even installing directly from GitHub.
- Or consider using an older Perl version.
- Or consider using cperl, a perl fork by perlcc maintainer Reini Urban. (Of course, using a fork is likely to break other things…)